# How to make this code a little more compact

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a construction that checks if a checkbox is checked (who can use more words 'check' so close to each other? =)) when the document loads and if it's checked, some rows in the table get hidden. It looks like this:

```
if (jQuery('#navbar_disabled').is(':checked')) {
        jQuery('#navbar_disabled').parents('tr').prev().hide();
        jQuery('#navbar_disabled').parents('tr').prev().prev().hide();
    }
```

I am sure there is a quick nice way to get rid of those 2 last '#navbar_disabled' and use something like 'this' or whatever instead. I know I can use something like `var navbar_checkbox_disabled=jQuery('#navbar_disabled')` and deal with it but I am looking for a more cute solution, if it is there. Thanks.

**UPDATE:** Why I am asking for the other solution than just assigning it to a new variable is that I need to use it on many elements like this:

```
jQuery('#company_address_disabled, #sociallinks_disabled, #contacts_mail_disabled, #navbar_disabled')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use it as a filter, which will make the jQuery object empty if it's not checked:

```
jQuery('#navbar_disabled:checked').parents('tr').prev().hide().prev().hide();
```

Comment: Wow, you are just a master, I am sure I would never realize this way, thanks. So cute, compact and does what I need!

Answer (score 1):

something like this maybe!?

```
$tr = $('#navbar_disabled').parents('tr').prev();
if ($('#navbar_disabled').is(':checked')) {
        $tr.hide();
        $tr.prev().hide();
    }
```

EDIT:

do you thinked to add class on theese elements!? i suppose your code look something like this:

```
<tr class='hide_me'><td>prev</td></tr>
<tr class='hide_me'><td>prev</td></tr>
<tr><td><input id="navbar_disabled" /></td></tr>


    if ($('#navbar_disabled').is(':checked')) {
            $('.hide_me').hide();
        }
```

Comment: I know about this variant but looking for something other if it exists. Thanks.